# Error when calling the selfdistruct method in solidity

Tags: solidity, solc, visual-studio-code

I am quite new to solidity, and I have not managed to find a solution for this problem.

I am passing the function an address but it says the following: 
"Invalid type for argument in function call. Invalid implicit conversion from address to address payable request."

```
address admin;

function endSale() public {
 require(msg.sender == admin);
 selfdestruct(admin);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elsewhere in the contract, find `address admin;` and declare it as `address payable admin;`.

Alternatively, `selfdestruct(msg.sender);` because `require(msg.sender == admin)`; ensures they are the same and `msg.sender` should be payable.

Answer (score 8):

As of Solidity 0.5.0, there are two different address types in solidity: `address` and `address payable`.

You can only transfer funds to an `address payable`.

Therefore, your problem will be fixed by making `admin` an `address payable`:

```
address payable admin;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can cast to `address payable` with this code:

```
selfdestruct(address(uint160(admin)));
```

**Solidity 0.6.x update:**

```
selfdestruct(payable(admin));
```